# How to check if HTML Element is empty?

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, phpunit

I have a page which when you submit a form, runs a javascript function which populates a table, there is also a link near by to delete that data from the table.

i am trying to make a test for this page in PHPUnit and checks if the HTML element in the table has no text in it, i have tried using

```
$this->isElementPresent('//form[@id="form"]//table[@id="table"]//tr/td[@class="cardno" and text()=""]');
```

but it returns false, using Selium IDE 2.4.0 in firefox i can check the xpath, it returns an error but when i remove the `and text()=''` part it works fine, i even checked by remove the class check and it returns an error

i learned about `assertElementValueEquals` and tried using that by passing in the xpath with the `text()` check and using a blank string, it returned

> Invalid response while accessing the Selenium Server at '[PAGE]': ERROR: This element has no value; is it really a form field?

i am wondering, how can i check if a HTML Element (in this case, the  element of the table) has no text in it

Comment: How about giving the element to a String variable and checking it with if statements?

Comment: @Arya i never thought about doing that, had to do a google search for the function that it's now working fine

Comment: good to hear you got it working

Comment: I don't know phpunit and am unsure because the method's named `isElementPresent` and not `isNodePresent`, but you could try to actually _match_ the `text()` node: `.../td[@class="cardno"]/text()`.